# Making and applying a custom design to a chart in Numbers

Tags: numbers, color, customization

I'm making a column chart about certain dice rolls in the game Descent: Second Edition, and the problem I'm having is that there are multiple dice of the same color in the standard rolls. For example, you could roll a red die, or two red die. I would like to be able to color code the dice rolls, but with the fact that this can cause ambiguity, I would like to be abler to make  checkered pattern, with line borders, so one can see if I'm talking about "red-red", "red", or "red-blue-yellow."

I would also like to be sure that when I apply this pattern that it repeats, so it doesn't end up stretched or squashed depending on the columns height. If it came down to it, I could devise a "pin stripe" design to make that moot, but, that's the thing, I don't know my options.

Here's what I have now. Notice the ambiguity and confusion in the colors.

[image: Current Color Scheme]

Here's what I would like to be able to do. Just by looking at it, you can tell what's being referred to.

[image: Wanted Color Scheme]

Comment: Your goal is somewhat unclear. A better description of what you're trying to accomplish--perhaps even a "cocktail napkin sketch"--would help the community to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Graphic Inspector* to set a gradient fill for any object, including a cell, in **Numbers**. This might work for the two-color combinations.

However, the best way to accomplish this would be to create an image file for each of the combinations and use the necessary file to fill the cell. The image can be scaled to fit within a single cell.

[image: screenshot: accessing the graphics inspector in Numbers]

---

[image: Screenshot: Selecting a fill style within the Graphics Inspector]